# Setting up path mapping in PHP and Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, eclipse-pdt

I have just setup my website locally so I can test my pages more easily.

Eclipse has been configured to use an XAMPP server locally.

The problem is that I want to map my project to a certain place in my website.

ie. In my Eclipse PHP project I have a folder called

```
com
```

I want this to map to

```
/com
```

in the webstie.

I tried to do this in the mapping section of the Eclipse server setup but it didn't work.  When I type

http://localhost/com/

It should go to my project folder, however, when I type other folder it should use the normal website folders.

how can I do this?

Comment: I'd make it virtual hosts, not folders

Comment: Are virtual hosts a better option that what I proposed below?

Comment: @jax: Not always / really. It is an alternative way to solve the problem, but it's not that quickly to setup and it has more implication on network configuration if you're in a LAN. So virtual hosts tend to be more inflexible as long as you don't have an admin that you can push to do things for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I edited the apache httpd.conf file like this and it works.

```
#Alias for com folder
Alias /com C:\PHP\workspace-php\php_project\com
<Directory "C:\PHP\workspace-php\php_project\com">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd created my Eclipse workspace exactly on [xampp]\htdocs folder