# 404 error in php eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I am trying to run a webpage using PHP Eclipse and I always get the 404 error ("The webpage cannot be found").

The page I am trying to run is a simple "hello world" variation in HTML. My web-server is set to localhost (in Window > Preferences > PHP servers). My localhost server is running, using the IIS server in Windows 7. When I go to `HTTP://localhost` on my browser i get the "It works!" message.

I've tried to access `http://localhost/tryout1/index.php` through my browser and I get "The requested URL /tryout1/index.php was not found on this server". I've tried it with\without the backslash and without the tryout1 library and I get the same message. By the way the project on Eclipse I am trying to run is tryout1, and the page is index.php.

What do i need to do in order to run the page in PHP Eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690279/eclipse-webserver-path-mapping-issue-with-php-project

Answer (score 0):

You need install php in iis, use web platfrom for install it,

here is the link : http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: hi, i installed the php for iis, and i still get the 404 error. thx for the suggestion though